# Combine 2 list functions into 1?

Tags: list, function, haskell, function-composition

How would I combine the following 2 functions:

```
replaceNth n newVal (x:xs)
 | n == 0 = newVal:xs
 | otherwise = x:replaceNth (n-1) newVal xs

replaceMthNth m n v arg = replaceNth m (replaceNth n v (arg !! m)) arg
```

into a single function?

Is it possible?

Comment: What do you want the new function to do?

Comment: @interjay I'd like it to convert a series of list elements e.g:

from:
[["Off","Off","Off"],["Off,"Off","Off"]]

ETA: Basically so I don't need the replaceNth function, I only need the replaceMthNth function

to:
[["Off","Off","Off"],["Off,"*On*","Off"]]

Comment: You mean that you want to implement `replaceMthNth` without calling other functions? If so, why would you want to do that? It would just complicate the code.

Comment: @interjay it's mainly for a small project and I can't call any other functions - that's the criteria.

Comment: @maclunian: "can't call any other functions" - well, could you use local functions? (like defined using a `where` clause)?  Or the y combinator.

Comment: cause I hate to tell you, but `replaceNth m` is a new function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty hideous but it does the job:

```
replacemn 0 0 z ((x : xs) : xss) = (z : xs) : xss
replacemn 0 n z ((x : xs) : xss) =
  let (ys : yss) = replacemn 0 (n-1) z (xs : xss)
  in ((x : ys) : yss)
replacemn m n z (xs:xss) = xs : replacemn (m-1) n z xss
```

Answer (score 2):

*Function composition*

Functions in Haskell may be composed at no cost. E.g. given two functions, `f` and `g`, you can compose them into a new function: `f . g`, which applies `g` to an argument, then applies `f` to the result. You should be able to use composition in the same way here.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here it is with no other named functions in the global namespace, or using any `where` or `let` clauses or any other global functions.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables,RankNTypes #-}
module Temp where
newtype Mu a = Mu (Mu a -> a)

replaceMthNth :: Int -> Int -> a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
replaceMthNth = (\h (f :: Int -> forall b . b -> [b] -> [b]) -> h f f)
                  ( \replaceNth replaceNth' ->
                    -- definition of replaceMthNth in terms of some replaceNth and replaceNth'
                    \m n v arg -> replaceNth m (replaceNth' n v (arg !! m)) arg
                  )
                  $
                    -- y combinator
                    ((\f -> (\h -> h $ Mu h) $ \x -> f $ (\(Mu g) -> g) x $ x) :: (a -> a) -> a) $
                    (\replaceNth ->
                      -- definition of replaceNth given a recursive definition 
                      (\(n::Int) newVal xs -> case xs of
                          [] -> []
                          (x:xs) -> if n == 0 then newVal:xs else x:replaceNth (n-1) newVal xs
                      )
                    )
```

Comment: This is great! :) However, you are using an additional function `fix`.

Comment: @Rotsor: I'm using lots of *anonymous* functions too... should we count those?

Comment: @Rotsor: Ok, I removed `fix`. (`Mu` is a constructor, not a function).

Comment: This is cool, but it should be noted that this is terribly advanced fro a beginner question about function composition.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what the question is at all :), but here is how I would implement it:

```
modifyNth :: Int -> (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a]
modifyNth n f (x:xs)
  | n == 0 = f x : xs
  | otherwise = x : modifyNth (n-1) f xs

replaceNthMth :: Int -> Int -> a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
replaceNthMth m n v = modifyNth m (modifyNth n (const v))
```

This way you don't need to traverse the list twice (first time with `!!`, second time with `replaceNth`)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a grotesque implementation that rebuilds the 2d list structure with nested list comprehensions over zips with infinite lists:

```
replaceMthNth :: Int -> Int -> a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
replaceMthNth m n v ass = [[if (x,y) == (m,n) then v else a
                            | (y, a) <- zip [0..] as]
                           | (x, as) <- zip [0..] ass]
```