# Weird error when using scoped type variables and the y combinator in haskell

Tags: haskell, type-systems, y-combinator, higher-rank-types

So I'm playing around with the y-combinator and anonymous functions, and I ran into this weird error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `t0 -> t1 -> t2'
            with actual type `forall b. b -> [b] -> [b]'
The lambda expression `\ (n :: Int) newVal xs -> ...'
has three arguments,
but its type `Int -> forall b. b -> [b] -> [b]' has only one
```

([source code that creates the error](https://gist.github.com/955412), and [version that I eventually got working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5876670/combine-2-list-functions-into-1/5877398#5877398))

If I [modify the types slightly to avoid Rank N polymorphism (use `forall b. Int -> b -> [b] -> [b]`)](https://gist.github.com/955714), the error is similar:

```
Couldn't match expected type `t0 -> t1 -> t2 -> t3'
            with actual type `forall b. Int -> b -> [b] -> [b]'
The lambda expression `\ (n :: Int) newVal xs -> ...'
has three arguments,
but its type `forall b. Int -> b -> [b] -> [b]' has none
```

Could someone explain to me why  `forall b. b -> [b] -> [b]` has no arguments?

Comment: What version of GHC are you using?  This looks like a bug in GHC 7 that prevents unification of implicitly and explicitly quantified types. http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/4347

Comment: @Carl: 7.0.3 - This looks like exactly the problem.  Upgrade your comment to an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Don Stewart: Making it type 1 by [changing the types to `forall b.Int -> b -> [b] -> [b]`](https://gist.github.com/955714) doesn't change the error much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using GHC 7, this appears to have the same root cause as the bug reported in http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/4347 .  While that bug report talks about impredicative polymorphism, it seems like it's most likely in a unification problem in higher-rank polymorphism. In your case, it's being triggered by your placement of the `forall`, which makes the type syntactically rank-2.

Note that this isn't really a bug.  The further clarification provided makes it clear this is intended behavior, in that polymorphic instantiations of types, including rank-N types and impredicative types, are not inferred.  Careful addition of type signatures can make it work.

But since the type wasn't intended to be higher-rank, at all, in your case, it's best to just get rid of that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you rather want

```
forall b. Int -> b -> [b] -> [b]
```

or really

```
Int -> forall b . b -> [b] -> [b]
```

I would read the latter: A function that takes an Int and returns *SOMETHING OPAQUE THAT IS MOST LIKELY NOT WHAT YOU THINK IT IS*.

Comment: possibly, but my current goal is to apply and refine my current understanding of `forall`, and, in particular, to understand why it is that `forall b. b -> [b] -> [b]` takes no arguments, as the error indicates.

Comment: Actually, those two are not different at all, since the forall scopes over the remainder of the type, and the function is rank-1 either way.

Comment: I should clarify...  The type is equivalent to a rank-1 type, even if it's written using rank-2 form.  That's what I actually meant.

Answer (score 0):

My guess was that you've written the  wrong types down.

Removing the type annotations helps somewhat, leading to less confusing errors:

```
A.hs:7:76:
    Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a0 = [a0]
    In the third argument of `replaceNth', namely `arg'
    In the expression: replaceNth m (replaceNth n v (arg !! m)) arg
```

so

```
 \m n v arg -> replaceNth m (replaceNth n v (arg !! m)) arg
```

has already got problems.

---

*Rank N types and lexically scoped type variables*

By using a `forall` not in an outermost position, you have stumbled into [rank *N* types](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Rank-N_types). The `forall` on your inner `b` says that it must be opaque, polymorphic, and unrelated to your other uses of the `b` type. This is likely not what you intended to do.

This is subtly distinct from *lexically scoped type variables*, which can also be introduced by a forall in the *outermost* position, as [described here](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#scoped-type-variables).

By removing the (I think) mistaken `forall`s in the non-outermost position, you will get much simpler type errors.

Comment: if I replace the argument to `(\replaceNth -> ...)` with a value of type `Int -> forall b.b -> [b] -> [b]` (like `undefined` or `const . const id`), I don't get any such error, so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: Note that that's a *rank N* type (the `forall` is on an inner position). Did you mean to introduce such a type there? It means your second `b` type will be distinct and unrelated to other `b`s in your type. Your question suggests you want scoped type variables, not rank N types.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, `forall b.b -> [b] -> [b]` has 4 `b`s, which I'll call b0, b1, b2, and b3; and `b0 ~ b1` is a constraint, but `b0 ~ b2` and `b0 ~ b3` are not?

Comment: `forall b.b -> [b] -> [b]` has three arguments, all of which must be the same type (which can be any type).